# Objects to be comma separated and with double quote

Tags: c#

I have an object array:

```
 object[] keys
```

I need to transform this array into a string which is comma separated and I did it by doing this:

```
var newKeys = string.Join(",", keys);
```

My problem here is I want this values to be double quoted.

ex:

```
"value1","value2","value3"
```

Comment: Do you know how to concatenate two or more strings? I.e. `var result = "a" + "b";`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for a code writing service

Answer (score 3):

```
var new= "\"" + string.Join( "\",\"", keys) + "\"";
```

To include a double quote in a string, you escape it with a backslash character, thus "\"" is a string consisting of a single double quote character, and "\", \"" is a string containing a double quote, a comma, a space, and another double quote.

Comment: +1 this is simpler and works pretty well, even with null and other types. The only drawback is the "" when the array is empty.

Comment: A trinary operator can fix the empty array:  `var new = keys.Length == 0 ? string.Empty : ...`

Comment: Also the OP's array is an `object` array. C# says `"cannot convert 'object[]' to 'string[]'"` (with my .NET 3.5).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes .NET 3.5 fails with the compilation error you mentioned. It works fine on .NET 4.0 which includes new handy implicit string converters.

Comment: .NET 4.0 has this overloaded method `public static string Join(string separator, params Object[] values)` which does the trick. `ToString` is applied to the objects.

Comment: Quite an interesting approach :). Was your intention to reduce the number of string allocations due to concatenations? Or did this just seem like a natural way to do it? I am referring to [@Larry's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24888776/69809) which feels like a more straightforward approach (and works for empty arrays as mentioned), although admittedly exhibits slightly worse performance for larger arrays.

Comment: @Groo: It just seemed like a natural way to do it, and I've done it that way in my own code.  Frankly, Larry's answer seems overly complicated to me and not so straight forward.  Linq is not the first way I think of to solve problems like this.  Also, you don't always want an empty array returned if the source array is empty in all scenarios.

Comment: I am a big fan of LINQ. I have to restrain myself to use it everywhere.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I think Linq has its uses.  I just don't think of this case as one of them.  And Linq doesn't come for free, there is a cost.  Usually it's negligible.

Answer (score 2):

Please give a try to this.

```
var keys = new object[] { "test1", "hello", "world", null, "", "oops"};

var csv = string.Join(",", keys.Select(k => string.Format("\"{0}\"", k)));
```

Because you have an `object[]` array, `string.Format` can deal with null as well as other types than strings. This solutions also works in .NET 3.5.

When the object[] array is empty, then a empty string is returned.

Answer (score 1):

If performance is the key, you can always use a `StringBuilder` to concatenate everything.

[Here's a fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nptVEH) to see it in action, but the main part can be summarized as:

```
// these look like snails, but they are actually pretty fast
using @_____ = System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object>;
using @______ = System.Func<object, object>;
using @_______ = System.Text.StringBuilder;

public static string GetCsv(object[] input)
{
    // use a string builder to make things faster
    var @__ = new StringBuilder();

    // the rest should be self-explanatory
    Func<@_____, @______, @_____>
    @____ = (_6,
    _2) => _6.Select(_2);
    Func<@_____, object> @_3 = _6
    => _6.FirstOrDefault();
    Func<@_____, @_____> @_4 = _8
    => _8.Skip(input.Length - 1);
    Action<@_______, object> @_ = (_9,
    _2) => _9.Append(_2);
    Action<@_______>
    @___ = _7 =>
    { if (_7.Length > 0) @_(
    @__, ",");
    }; var @snail =
    @____(input, (@_0 =>
    { @___(@__); @_(@__, @"""");
    @_(@__, @_0); @_(@__, @"""");
    return @__; }));
    var @linq = @_4(@snail);
    var @void = @_3(@linq);

    // get the result
    return @__.ToString();
}
```

Comment: It's too easy and obvious to be an accepted answer. But +1 anyway for daring it.